# Assign AnonymousUserMixin to a real user

Tags: python, flask-login, apache-superset

I want to make a Superset app<sup>[1](http://superset.incubator.apache.org)</sup> that is configured to use `flask-login` for auth work without any auth at all. Anonymous users are already assigned/executed as the `AnonymousUserMixin` but parts of the app require a username and presumably ID.

My idea is to create an Admin user in the database and somehow assign `AnonymousUserMixin` to always be equal to that user. How would I do that and where in the flask-login or superset code would I be looking to do this?

Note: authentication to get into this application will already be taken care of and so security implications are moot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Superset uses as [Flask-AppBuilder](http://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/) as the underlying web framework. [Its configuration](http://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#configuration-keys) includes:

> AUTH_TYPE = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
>   This is the authentication type
>
> - 0 = Open ID
> - 1 = Database style (user/password)
> - 2 = LDAP, use AUTH_LDAP_SERVER also
> - 3 = uses web server environ var REMOTE_USER
> - 4 = USE ONE OR MANY OAUTH PROVIDERS

Our interest is `3`. Because Superset [supports middleware](http://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#middleware) setting predefined user is as easy as (in `superset_config.py`):

```
AUTH_TYPE = 3

class PredefinedUserMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        environ['REMOTE_USER'] = 'admin'
        return self.app(environ, start_response)

ADDITIONAL_MIDDLEWARE = [PredefinedUserMiddleware]
```

Comment: thanks - that's going to map every request to a user in the database with the *username* "admin"?

Comment: @MarkSilverberg Yes, in my brief experiment it did so. *admin* was the user created on installation. Give it a try.